# How to get Player duration, current Time, and video frames or Seek Position (JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html5-video, html5-audio

I am able to put this code together to get player duration, current time, and to derive a value which i use to update the progress bar width.

**Such As**

```
var slideOff=Math.floor((100 / tDuration) *( tCurrent)); 


progBar.css({width:slideOff+'%'});
```

My issue is that i want also to be able to the get the seek position.

For example with the code below is working fine but the seek figure is not tally or the same with current time .

if you run this code on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dego247/UYX7G/) you will get somthing like this:

**Duration  29:05**

**Current Time  2:25**

**SeekPosition   1:44** This is the issue i want the seek position to be the same as current time when computed.

**Html**

```
<div id="seekbar">

<div id="seeker"></div>

<div id="seekLay" ></div>

</div>
Duration<span id="currenT">00:00</span>

<br/>
Current Time<span id="durationT">00:00</span>


<br/>
SeekPosition <span id="resulk">00:00</span>
```

**Css**

```
#seekbar{
    border:none;
    width:480px;
    height:6px; 
    background-color:#00ffcc;   
    position:relative;
    margin:auto;

    }

    #seekLay{
    margin:0;
    height:4px;
    background-color:#001001;
    position:relative;
    top:1px;}

    #seeker{
    width:6px;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;  
    left:0;    
    background-color:red;
    cursor:pointer;}
span{margin-left:30px;}
```

**Javascript**

```
String.prototype.pad = function(l, s){
return (l -= this.length) > 0 ? (s = new Array(Math.ceil(l / s.length) + 1).join(s)).substr(0, s.length) + this + s.substr(0, l - s.  length) : this;}

function playerTime(dcurT) {
       var tCurrent = dcurT  ,//player.getCurrentTime(),
           tDuration= 1745,  //player.getDuration(),
           dbar=$("#seekbar"),
           progressBar=$("#seeker"),
           progBar=$("#seekLay"),
           currenT = tCurrent,
           slideOff=Math.floor((100 / tDuration) *( tCurrent));      
    //Get current time
$('span#currenT').html(Math.floor(tDuration/ 60) + ":" + (tDuration % 60).toFixed().pad(2, "0"));
    //get duration
$('span#durationT').html(Math.floor(tCurrent / 60) + ":" + (tCurrent % 60).toFixed().pad(2, "0"));     
    //Update bars
progressBar.css({marginLeft:slideOff+'%'});
progBar.css({width:slideOff+'%'});

      //Get seek position

    var ratio=Math.floor((progBar.width())/progressBar.width()),           
        xpos=Math.floor( tDuration* (ratio / 100));

$('span#resulk').html(Math.floor(xpos / 60) + ":" + (xpos % 60).toFixed().pad(2, "0"));

      }
playerTime(145);//change

//Out Put
//Duration  29:05 
//Current Time   2:25 
//SeekPosition 1:44
```

I know this won't take you 5 minutes to figure out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Simply change this line

```
var ratio=Math.floor((progBar.width())/progressBar.width()),           
        xpos=Math.floor( tDuration* (ratio / 100));
```

============

## Replace It with  this line

```
var xpos=Math.floor(tDuration*progBar.width()/dbar.width());
```

==============